# remote access to apache web server mac os X

Tags: ipad, apache

finally got apache web server up and running.(plus mysql) but I can only access it on the on the host computer. does anyone know how to access the apache server remotely?

My main goal is to access mobile web pages via apache server with an iPad for development / troubleshooting issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - check the Error Log - it may tell you about config or firewall issues.

Secondly - check with 'lsof' or 'netstat -na' if Apache is listening on * (all interfaces) or on the IP address you expect it is listening.

If that is *not* the case - read up on the 'Listen' directive in httpd.conf.

If that is the case - then an IP issue outside apache is blocking things. Check the firewall, check that you can ping this address, check if you can 'telnet' to this address/port (to rule out your browser going through some proxy).

And take things from there.

Dw.